# ASP.NET MVC: Retrieving form fields with the same name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there are way to retrieve form fields with the same name besides using modelbinders or comma splitting.

I have a few textfields with the same name and i need to loop through them and retrieve each value.

Thank you

Comment: can I ask why do you want form fields with the same name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FormCollection is a NameValueCollection.  That means you can do:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection form)
{
  // ModelBinder will set "form" appropriately
  foreach(var value in form.Getvalues("duplicatedFieldname"))
  {
    //do something with value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Even easier:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(string[] fieldName)
```

Or use `List<string>` if you prefer that instead of `string[]`.