# Is it possible to pipe delimit forms encoded values instead of commas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Currently, I have a set of textboxes that are dynamically created with the same `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="SameName" value="Value1" />
<input type="text" name="SameName" value="Value2" />
```

On the server side I am receiving a submitted form (POST) and accessing `Request.Form["SameName"]` and the value is `Value1,Value2`.

My question is, is it possible to change the delimiter from a comma to a pipe (or some other character) some way?

I can't just replace commas with pipe because I need to delimit the different fields:

```
<input type="text" name="SameName" value="Val,ue1" />
<input type="text" name="SameName" value="Value2" />
```

would be:

> Val,ue1,Value2

Suggesting I have 3 text fields instead of two.  So a simple `Replace(',','|')` isn't helpful.

Comment: @nordic that is probably what I will end up doing, but I was just seeing if there was a way I could manipulate how ASP.Net derives that comma seperated string.

Comment: never mind, I think you got the best answer :)

Comment: Do you want to have a deliminated string in the end or do you want to have the different values in different variables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In reality, the POST sends the values of the two inputs individually. You're seeing the concatenated version because of how you're accessing it from Request.Form (which is a NameValueCollection).

To be able to differentiate between the different POSTed values, you can use [`GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte.aspx)

```
string[] values = Request.Form.GetValues("SameName");
```

Comment: I was typing this up as a suggestion when it appeared. This is the route to go. +1

Answer (score 1):

If it is a string you can use the string.replace method and tell it the char you want to replace, and what you want to replace it with.

```
string sr = "Value1,Value2";
sr.Replace(",","|");
```

EDIT

I think you can assign the return of the request.form to an array, then loop through the array to get the values individually and do what you want with them.  This would get around the problem of having a comma in the results.

Comment: What if I have commas in one of the text boxes?  I will add an edit to clarify this.

Comment: Good point, could you post your code where you are assigning the return value of `Request.Form["SameName"]` ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an excellent example of what you are trying to do:

```
public function MyAction(FormCollection form) as String
    dim sb = new Text.StringBuilder
    for each value as string in form.Getvalues("SameName")
        sb.Append(Server.UrlEncode(value) & ",")

    next
    'Remove trailing comma if you want
    If Right(sb.ToString, 1) = "," Then
        retVal.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1)
    End If

'Do other fun stuff here if you want

    return sb.ToString

End Function
```

References: [ASP.NET MVC: Retrieving form fields with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984717/asp-net-mvc-retrieving-form-fields-with-the-same-name) - Multiple same name fields in c#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx - URL Encode function